# Display list + glsl

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I can use display list + glsl? something like using vbo + glsl.

if this can be, you can write an example.

Comment: In short, you cannot use them directly. You will need to put them into some format that can be piped into glsl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in terms of OpenGL-2, yes you can use GLSL shaders on geometry drawn through a display list that was compiled from immediate mode calls. The question is: Why would you want to do this?

OpenGL-3 removed display lists (good riddance). So don't expect it to work for any GLSL version beyond 1.2x.x

Comment: Well, my idea is to create a sprite using glsl and I thought I could use this instead of glBegin () / glEnd ()

Comment: @JavierRamírez: Shaders (GLSL) control the process how geometry is drawn. They don't *define* the geometry. See it like this way: You get a shelf from IKEA. The single parts are what you put into vertex arrays/buffers and batch for drawing using glDraw/glBegin. The instruction manual in the box are the shaders that tell how to turn those pieces into a shelf, or in terms of OpenGL how to turn the formless geometric attributes into locations on the screen and how to colorize the pixels they cover.

Comment: I feel I have to give a -1 for this since it does not remotely help to solve the problem.

Comment: @Joehot200: Not every problem has a solution.

Comment: +1 because it helped me understand the relationship between VBOs and Shaders better (been searching the all over the internet for that)